# Unexpected results when attempting to access Tomcat 6 HTTPS connector using HTTP

Tags: tomcat, https, tomcat6

I configured an instance of Tomcat following this article: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html. I commented out HTTP connector because I want my demo application to be accessible only via HTTPS. I configured HTTPS connector as such:

```
   <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystorePass="nopass"
           keystoreFile="/home/someuser/.keystore" keyAlias="tomcat" />
```

Everything works fine when I hit the URL of the my demo application's servlet using HTTPS.

When I tried to hit it using HTTP URL, I expected it to return 403 or similar error. Instead I got download of some small (11 bytes?) binary file with the name matching the name of the servlet.

Did anyone experienced similar issue? How did you resolve it? What should I check to make sure I did everything right?

**EDIT:** I tried hitting the same connector using curl instead of the browser and noticed that it doesn't return any headers. Oh, and the size of the response is 7 bytes, not 11.

**EDIT 2:** This is the security-related part of the web.xml of my demo application:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Servlet</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/SecureServlet</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>connect</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <description>The role required to connect to the application
    </description>
    <role-name>connect</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Comment: I asked the same question on [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/632048/how-to-redirect-http-request-on-https-port/632090?noredirect=1#632090) yesterday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tested this by commenting out the HTTP Connector in `server.xml` forcing the app to work on HTTPS

> https://localhost:8443/testapp

works as expected

> http://localhost:8080/testapp

returns *a 404*

> http://localhost:8443/testapp

Note the ***incorrect*** ***mix of protocol*** ***and port*** returns a small stream of garbage which is rendered in IE and as binary in Firefox

this is of 7 bytes

Can you recheck if you are seeing the **3rd scenario** which should not happen in a natural case but only if someone fiddles with the URL?

Okay, I tested using `CONFIDENTIAL` but it still does not redirect the http on 8443 to https. I'm guessing that only comes into picture when the user has tried http on the valid 8080 port.

Using Fiddler, I see that the headers coming back are non-existent and the junk response.

> HTTP/1.1 200 This buggy server did not return headers

This seems to be the standard behaviour, and end-users who access the app in this manner will see junk as expected.

If you really need to, you [could try writing](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html) your own [custom Tomcat Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html) which acts like a Filter to take care of this special case and redirect the users to SSL

Comment: The 3rd scenario is exactly what I'm seeing: no headers and a 7 bytes worth of binary data. I can see that you pretty much got the same results following more or less the same steps that I did. I just wonder if this is the correct behavior. I would expect Tomcat either refusing connection or returning a 40x code and certainly not sending some binary data. And thanks for the tip on IE! On any given PC I usually use it once to download a good browser.

Comment: Is your reqt actually to server all traffic via https? You can force even http onto https with a `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>`

Comment: I edited question by adding the relevant part of my application's web.xml. I already have confidential transport guarantee specified. I wonder if I need to configure any error pages in the web.xml.

Comment: JoseK, is result displayed after incorrect mix of protocol (http) and port (8443) is insecure? This has come up as a security issue to me after security audit of my application on tomcat. No matter what I try, its showing five small rectangles in IE. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @waprau: I dont understand how this is a security risk. This is the browser default behaviour for any application with http on the wrong https port. So this is not only for your app.